# Automatically calculate data from collected database values

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown that has products, and once the user selects a product, it automatically fills two input fields with the price and levy of that selected product. Is there a way using JavaScript to **automatically** calculate those two values and display it in a third input field.

The issue is that I have to manually change one of the input fields in order for the calculation to show. What I need, once the product gets selected it already displays the calculation in the "total" input field.

```js
document.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  let mySelect = document.getElementById("item");
  mySelect.addEventListener("change", () => document.getElementById("first_calc_1").value = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-price"));
  mySelect.addEventListener("change", () => document.getElementById("second_calc_1").value = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-levy"));
  mySelect.addEventListener("change", () => document.getElementById("id").value = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-id"));
});

$("#orders").on('input', 'input.first_calc,input.second_calc', function() {
  getTotalCost($(this).attr("for"));
});

function getTotalCost(ind) {
  let number_1 = document.getElementById('first_calc_' + ind).value;
  let number_2 = document.getElementById('second_calc_' + ind).value;
  let total = number_1 * number_2;
  $('#total_' + ind).val(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <form id="orders" action="" method="post">
    <select id="item" name="get_value">
      <option value="Guitar" data-price="2500" data-levy="25">Guitar</option>
      <option value="Drums" data-price="3500" data-levy="35">Drums</option>
      <option value="Trello" data-price="5500" data-levy="45">Trello</option>
    </select>
    <input class="first_calc" type="number" id="first_calc_1" for="1">
    <input class="second_calc" type="number" id="second_calc_1" for="1">
    <input type="text" id="total_1">
  </form>
```

Comment: Can you add some of the rendered HTML (ie: view source, copy, paste ) so that we can see the data contained within the HTML. `"Is there a way using JavaScript to automatically calculate those two values "` - yes

Comment: Are there multiple forms all the same or is it just this one form?

Comment: "Is there a way using JavaScript to automatically calculate those two values" - yes. Why not use some code to calculate the data? Also, please clarify the problem itself. Is this a JS problem, an HTML problem, a PHP problem, or a MySQL problem? Remove the tags and the code snippets that are not relevant

Comment: Hi @ProfessorAbronsius, there is only 1 form.

Comment: Hi @NicoHaase, i rectified the tags, my mistake i misunderstood that feature.

Comment: If there is only a single form I m confused why the ID attributes are numerically suffixed as they are... such as `<select id="item<?php echo $id; ?>"` etc... this usually happens when there are multiple elements and the user does not know how to process the DOM efficiently without `document.getElementById` etc

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, i have removed the additional part from the ID and edited the scripts.

Comment: Hi @mplungjan, i am busy working on a HTML rendered code snippet for you.

Comment: 1. IDs need to be unique so remove the orders from the div. 2. You have jQuery, why not use it? Also use 3.6.0 instead of such an ancient version

Comment: Assuming you have more than one of these, I strongly suggest you use jQuery in a proper way. the answers below might have helped you fix YOUR version but a better approach is here: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/vq1r2nxz/ I will post it when the question is reopened

Comment: Here is for one form https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/anmso3fc/

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Please reopen the question so others like me can answer

Comment: @NicoHaase The question has enough information to warrant a reopen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the following line as well so that it will trigger the getTotalCost function on change

```
mySelect.addEventListener("change", () => getTotalCost(i));
```

(where i=1 in your case)

So change the following block:

```
mySelect.addEventListener("change", () => document.getElementById("first_calc_1").value = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-price"));
mySelect.addEventListener("change", () => document.getElementById("second_calc_1").value = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-levy"));
mySelect.addEventListener("change", () => document.getElementById("id").value = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-id"));
```

to

```
mySelect.addEventListener("change", () => document.getElementById("first_calc_1").value = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-price"));
mySelect.addEventListener("change", () => document.getElementById("second_calc_1").value = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-levy"));
mySelect.addEventListener("change", () => document.getElementById("id").value = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-id"));

mySelect.addEventListener("change", () => getTotalCost(1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this the sort of thing that you were trying to accomplish?

```js
/*
  Bind a `delegated` event listener to a common ancestor element. In this case it
  is the document itself but could easily be the parent form.
  
  The listener will register to all `change` events but will only process those
  events originating from an element of our choosing, in this instance the `select`
  menu.
*/

document.addEventListener('change',e=>{
  if( e.target.name=='get_value' ){
    /*
      Find the form element as the basis for searching for
      child elements by name using dot notation for simplicity.
    */
    let form=e.target.parentNode;
    /*
      The event target is the `select` menu so we can use that
      to obtain the selected `option` element by using the
      `selectedIndex` property, and thus access the dataset
      attributes for that particular option.
    */
    let option=e.target.options[e.target.options.selectedIndex];
    /*
      Set the values of the input elements and calculate the
      total using basic arithmetic.
    */
    form.first_calc.value=Number(option.dataset.price);
    form.second_calc.value=Number(option.dataset.levy);
    
    form.total.value=form.first_calc.value * form.second_calc.value
  }
});
```

```html
<div data-id='orders'>
  <!-- 
    Elements with ID attributes (or other) containing numeric suffixes 
    become cumbersome to work with. There are cleaner methods of interacting with
    the DOM than by referring to the ID of an element.
  -->
  <form name='orders' method='post'>
    <select name='get_value'>
      <option value='banana' data-price='23' data-levy='5' data-id='2'>Banana</option>
      <option value='apple' data-price='18' data-levy='8' data-id='4'>Apple</option>
      <option value='carrot' data-price='4' data-levy='1' data-id='54'>Carrot</option>
      <option value='tomato' data-price='12' data-levy='2' data-id='6'>Tomato</option>
    </select>
    
    <input class='first_calc' name='first_calc' type='number' />
    <input class='second_calc' name='second_calc' type='number' />
    <input type='text' name='total' />
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("orders").addEventListener` makes more sense if OP removes the ID from the div

Comment: I was basing this on the original code which did feature IDs with numeric suffixes and, to be honest, I find the use of numbers on the end of IDs to be a poor approach ... I do see your point of tightening the delegated parent to a more specific element though